# Why after using ''.join() i get whitespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im beginner in programming and python is my first language, can someone explain to me why i get whitespaces after executing this code? Its part of code where i have to create password generator according to exercise number 16 at practicepython.org.

```
def strong():
  result = []
  symbols = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '=',
'+']
  alpha = list(string.ascii_letters)
  numbers = list(range(1,10))
  leng = random.randint(2,3)
  for i in range(leng):
    randomise = random.randint(2,3)
    print(randomise)
    if randomise ==2:
        result += random.choice(symbols)
        result += random.choice(str(numbers))
        result += random.choice(symbols)
        result += random.choice(alpha)
        result += random.choice(str(numbers))
        result += random.choice(alpha)
    elif randomise ==3:
        result += random.choice(symbols)
        result += random.choice(str(numbers))
        result += random.choice(symbols)
        result += random.choice(str(numbers))
        result += random.choice(alpha)
        result += random.choice(symbols)
        result += random.choice(alpha)
        result += random.choice(str(numbers))
        result += random.choice(alpha)
  print(result)
  print(''.join(result))
```

Comment: Show your output. There is no whitespace when I run it.

Comment: I also don't see any whitespace in `''.join(result)`

Comment: @geoffspear in my case `&b Z=9=,k-Q7n#1(,o+L A`

Comment: `str(numbers) == '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'`. And there's obvious white space in there.

Comment: If you are trying to call the `strong()` function you are not returning anything. You miss a `return` statement.

Comment: btw your print statements are out of the function scope

Comment: Everything is fine in my text editor but when i copied it here it just looked like that. Sorry about that should have looked at it one more time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is here:

```
random.choice(str(numbers))
```

`str(numbers)` stringifies the list as a whole, yielding `'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'` and this is where white space enters your list of possible characters.

I'd suggest using `string.digits`:

```
numbers = string.digits
```

As noted in the comments below, this then includes '`0`', so if this is a problem, another option would be

```
numbers = '123456789'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help.

Comment: @Esgath - `string.digits` includes 0 so you may need to strip this

Comment: @Sayse - it's not a problem, thank you for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 2):

you just need replace the

```
random.choice(str(numbers))
```

to

```
str(random.choice(numbers))
```

and your code should be:

```
if randomise ==2:
    result += random.choice(symbols)
    result += str(random.choice(numbers))
    result += random.choice(symbols)
    result += random.choice(alpha)
    result += str(random.choice(numbers))
    result += random.choice(alpha)
elif randomise ==3:
    result += random.choice(symbols)
    result += str(random.choice(numbers))
    result += random.choice(symbols)
    result += str(random.choice(numbers))
    result += random.choice(alpha)
    result += random.choice(symbols)
    result += random.choice(alpha)
    result += str(random.choice(numbers))
    result += random.choice(alpha)
```